# Is there an equivalent of node voltage analysis in mechanical and civil engineering?

Tags: structural-analysis, statics

When analyzing the behavior of an electrical circuit, the core of the work often involves performing node voltage analysis. This allows you to determine voltage drops and currents of interest in the circuit in an efficient way.

Is there an equivalent in mechanical and civil engineering? My guess is that analysis of the static forces is often important, but is it as fundamental as circuit analysis? And is there a method similar to node voltage analysis that can be applied in formulaic manner to achieve the result?

Comment: Mechanical engineering deals with many different phenomena, not one. The pneumatic/hydraulic systems are entirely anologous to electrical circuits as are some spring/mass rotation systems. etc etc. But yes many similar things are available across different domains of mechanical engineering. (electricals used to be one subdomain but many subdomains still exist in mechanical engineering, which quite frankly is everything that does not fit any of the other engineering categories)

Comment: Finite element analysis?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. There is an analysis system called *power bond graphs* which allows you to convert a mechanical system with springs, masses, levers, gears and whatnot into something that looks like a circuit diagram. Power bond graphs then allow you to follow a cookbook recipe that yields a set of partial differential equations for the whole system which can be solved on a computer. The standard textbook on this technique is Karnopp and Rosenberg, *System Dynamics: A Unified Approach*.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually familiar with bond graphs, i do wonder though if they are quite niche.

Comment: Karnopp taught me bond graphs 45 years ago when I was in grad school. Laptop computers today can run dynamic systems analysis apps which probably have obsoleted bond graphs as an analysis tool, but that was not the case back in the day. -NN

Comment: @nielsnielsen bond graphs are offcourse still there in use when the programmers derive the system. Offcourse same can be said about circuit analysis a computer does it for me in day to day work too.

Comment: @dmh like i said physical systems are not one thing. Therefore yes this is somewhat niche but then nearly everything is since a person building a mechanism has a different need than a person making a stationary structure or a person doing optics.  Bond graphs extend though to any realm, you can use bond graphs to describe the circuit too. Personally i think that the fundamental one is modal analysis. because it can tie in structural analysis and bond graphs into one dynamic system. But it does not fit your description.